# Extended Hippie Completion in Pycharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

Suppose you created a class class `Story`, and you also created an Admin panel for this, `StoryAdmin`. This is referring to a common scenario in making a Django Application.

Now, in story admin, you want to assign certain fields to be displayed. There is currently no auto-complete for this, but there is hippie complete. `ALT` + `/`.

But this only goes so far as suggestions within the current page one is working in. How does one extend hippie complete to extend to other files that one has created?

This feature is available in Sublime Text 2. If a more elaborate example of what I am talking about needs to be demonstrated, please say so in the comments.

*If this question is not appropriate for SO, vote to close it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported yet in PyCharm, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57940).